# get till end of string after first space

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I need to split a string as follows, when I try with with split_part no luck

```
select split_part('8 HAMPSHIRE RD',' ',2)
```

Expected output: HAMPSHIRE RD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html):

```
select regexp_replace('8 HAMPSHIRE RD', '.*?\s', '');

 regexp_replace 
----------------
 HAMPSHIRE RD
(1 row)
```

An alternative solution using string manipulation functions:

```
with my_table(str) as (
    values ('8 HAMPSHIRE RD')
)
select right(str, -strpos(str, ' '))
from my_table;
```

If you want to skip the first word if it contains only digits you should use `\d` (digit) instead of `.` (any char):

```
select regexp_replace('8 HAMPSHIRE RD', '\d*?\s', '');
```

Comment: thanks, but can you please explain what '.*?\s' means?  Does \s means space and . means starting from position 1 and *? means till the end of the string

Comment: The expression means *any string till first space including this space*. The `?` sign forces the regex to be lazy (i.e. to find first space).

Comment: I marked this question as answered, however any assistance on checking the space after numeric only? Because above expression gives me "BOX 203" when I apply it on address like "PO BOX 203" where I expect the result as "PO BOX 203". Sorry, I should have included this example in my question before

Answer (score 3):

A cheaper solution without a regular expression:

```
SELECT substring (
          '8 HAMPSHIRE RD'
          FROM position(' ' IN '8 HAMPSHIRE RD') + 1
       );
```